Symbolising "Every team in league S has exactly one rival in league S"
Given Predicates:

T(x, y): Team x plays in league y.
R(x, y): Team x is a rival of team y.

Note: R is symmetric: R(x, y) = R(y, x).
Statement to Translate:
Every team in league S  has exactly one rival, that is also in league S.
My Solution Attempt:
$$\forall x \left( T(x, S) \to \exists y \left[ T(y, S) \land R(x, y) \land \forall z \left( \left( T(z, S) \land R(x, z) \right) \to z = y \right) \right] \right)$$
The Provided Solution:
$$\forall x \forall y \exists z \left[ \left( T(x, S) \to \left( R(x, z) \land T(z, S) \right) \right) \land \left( \left( T(y, S) \land R(x, y) \right) \to \left( y \ne z \land y \ne x \right) \right) \right]$$
The provided solution seems counterintuitive to me. Which translation correctly captures the original statement? Could someone explain the reasoning behind the correct translation and clarify any misunderstandings?

I agree with @ryang that the statement is ambiguous in exactly the way that @ryang is pointing out. Maybe that is the difference between your solution and the Provided Solution?  No, it is not.
On the first interpretation, a team has exactly one rival in League $S$, though the team could still have other rivals not in League $S$.  Your sentence correctly captures the first interpretation:
$$\forall x \left( T(x, S) \to \exists y \left[ T(y, S) \land R(x, y) \land \forall z \left( \left( T(z, S) \land R(x, z) \right) \to z = y \right) \right] \right)$$
On the second interpretation, a team has exactly one rival (between all the Leagues) and that one rival is in League $S$. That you can capture by:
$$\forall x \left( T(x, S) \to \exists y \left[ T(y, S) \land R(x, y) \land \forall z \left( R(x, z) \to z = y \right) \right] \right)$$
The Provided Solution is equivalent to neither of these:
$$\forall x \forall y \exists z \left[ \left( T(x, S) \to \left( R(x, z) \land T(z, S) \right) \right) \land \left( \left( T(y, S) \land R(x, y) \right) \to \left( y \ne z \land y \ne x \right) \right) \right]$$
Given the presence of the $T(y,S)$ as well as the $T(z,S)$, it pretty clearly tried to follow the first interpretation like you did, but it miserably failed in doing so. Below, let me try to explain what the Provided Solution is saying.
First, one thing the provided solution does is to insist that the rival of a team cannot be that team itself. It is debatable whether one needs to include that or not. So, let's take it out, and in fact let's also swap the $y$'s and $z$'s to make it more closely resemble your solution:
$$\forall x \forall z \exists y [ ( T(x, S) \to ( R(x, y) \land T(y, S) ) \land ( ( T(z, S) \land R(x, z) ) \to z \ne y  ) ]$$
Second, the Provide Solution has a parentheses problem: with the parentheses placed as they are, the body is a conjunction, with only the first half predicated on $x$ being a team from League $S$, but not the second half.  But clearly that second half needs to be restricted to teams $x$ from League $S$ as well.  So, already the Provided solution is not correct, but let's just say they made a small error and fix that to make it more like yours:
$$\forall x \forall z \exists y (T(x, S) \to [ ( R(x, y) \land T(y, S) ) \land ( ( T(z, S) \land R(x, z) ) \to z \ne y ) ] ) $$
Third: note the $z \neq y$ claim in the Provided Solution, whereas you have $ z= y$.  You are correct, while the Provided Solution is obviously not correct … the Provided Solution ends up saying that for all rivals $z$ of $x$, there is some rival $y$ of $x$ that is not $z$. So note, this would not be true if $x$ has exactly one rival ... and would be true if $x$ has multiple rivals (so that for the $y$ you can pick a rival other than what you picked for $z$).  Clearly this is not what we want.
OK, so again let us see this as a typo and assume they meant $y = z$ the same way you (correctly!) have it:
$$\forall x \forall z \exists y (T(x, S) \to [ ( R(x, y) \land T(y, S) ) \land ( ( T(z, S) \land R(x, z) ) \to z = y ) ] ) $$
But even now the statement is still not correct! This statement says that for any rival $z$ of $x$ there is a rival $y$ of $x$ that is the same as $z$. Well duh! Simply set $y=z$ for any $z$. So this is trivially true as soon as $x$ has any rivals at all, and does not rule out multiple rivals in the same league $S$.
As I see it, part of the problem is that the Provided Solution tried to put all quantifiers on the outside, i.e. provide a statement that is in Prenex Normal Form. Yes, using the Prenex laws we can always do that, but you have to be careful about both the type of quantifiers (because sometimes the type changes when applying the Prenex Laws), as well as the order of the quantifiers. And that is what went wrong in the Provided Solution. They ended up with a $\forall z \exists y$ construction, while yours ends up being a $\exists y \forall z $ construction, and those have completely different meanings.
Indeed, if you try to push the qunatifiers back in, you'll find that you can't put the $\forall z$ where you want to put it (which is where you have it):
$$\forall x (T(x, S) \to \forall z \exists y [ ( R(x, y) \land T(y, S) ) \land ( ( T(z, S) \land R(x, z) ) \to z = y ) ] ) $$
which is further evidence that the provided Solution is not correct.
So, all in all, it was a very bad Provided Solution!
Finally, I want to stress how the Provided Solution is a great example of why it is often very confusing to put all quantifiers at the front of the statement. Indeed, I really detest the practice, if not insistence, of some texts and authors to always have all quantifiers at the front of the statement when it comes to symbolziation. It makes them hard to read and interpret. And, trying to create symbolizations of that kind yourselves, you can very easily make mistakes, and I think the Provided Solution is a good example of that. So, instead of insisting on Prenex Normal Form, I always urge students to do exactly what you did: introduce the quantifiers only when it is 'their time'. So, you did good work!


Bram28, thanks for expanding on my answer, and I salute you for deconstructing the provided solution, at which I could only scratch and tilt head.

@ryang Thanks!  Assuming the OP copied that correctly from the source, that was indeed a bit of a head scratcher… the addition of $y \ne x$ was understandable, and the $y \ne z$ and the change of order of the quantifiers just plainly and  clearly wrong, but it took me a while to realize that something was going wrong with the parentheses as well. :P



Every team in league $S$ has exactly one rival, that is also in league $S.$


Let $Sx$ denote that team $x$ plays in league $S.$
The given natural-language sentence is ambiguous between these two readings:

Every team in league S has exactly one rival that is also in league S.
(I.e., some team in $S$ may have a rival in $S$ and a rival not in $S.)$ $$\forall x\Big(Sx\to\exists y\forall z\,(z=y\leftrightarrow Rxz\land Sz)\Big),\tag1$$

Every team in league S has exactly one rival, which is also in league S. $$\forall x\Big(Sx\to\exists y\big(Sy\land \forall z\,(z=y\leftrightarrow Rxz)\big)\Big),\tag2$$


To add that a team cannot be its own rival, we can write $\forall x\Big(Sx\to\exists y\, \color\red{(y\ne x \land\, }\forall z\,(z=y\leftrightarrow Rxz\land Sz)\color\red)\Big)\tag{1a}$$\forall x\Big(Sx\to\exists y\big(\color\red{y\ne x\land\,}Sy\land \forall z\,(z=y\leftrightarrow Rxz)\big)\Big)\tag{2a}$ instead.
The provided solution

$$\forall x \forall y \exists z \left[ \left( T(x, S) \to \left( R(x, z) \land T(z, S) \right) \right) \\\land \left( \left( T(y, S) \land R(x, y) \right) \to \left( y \ne z \land y \ne x \right) \right) \right]$$

doesn't seem to agree with any of the four suggestions above, so I think it is incorrect, whereas your solution attempt

$$\forall x \left( T(x, S) \to \exists y \left[ T(y, S) \land R(x, y) \land \forall z \left( \left( T(z, S) \land R(x, z) \right) \to z = y \right) \right] \right).$$

is clearly logically equivalent to statement $(1).$
